# cannot implicitly convert type using ASP.Net Entity data model

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using ASP.Net Entity data model see in Image (Model.edmx) few days before it works fine but I got error see in diagram but when I run project it work fine but when  re-build solution I got error see image in second image. if

I Change like following

```
var content = contextObj.PersonalInfoes.Where(a => a.StudID == rolltemp).FirstOrDefault();
```

then error goes I donot understand why this error comes

I [image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you've two class with the name `PersonalInfo`

Comment: no I checked there is no duplicate class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem occurs because I change project name StudentSys to StudentMgmSystem

```
 File Name : Model.edmx.diagram
```

after changed like following problem solved

```
   <EntityTypeShape EntityType="StudentMgmSystemModel.Login" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="0.75" IsExpanded="true" />
    <EntityTypeShape EntityType="StudentMgmSystemModel.HostelDetail" Width="1.5" PointX="5.375" PointY="0.75" />
    <EntityTypeShape EntityType="StudentMgmSystemModel.PersonalInfo" Width="1.5" PointX="2.75" PointY="0.875" />
```

before

```
 <EntityTypeShape EntityType="StudentSysModel.Login" Width="1.5" PointX="0.75" PointY="0.75" IsExpanded="true" />
    <EntityTypeShape EntityType="StudentSysModel.HostelDetail" Width="1.5" PointX="5.375" PointY="0.75" />
    <EntityTypeShape EntityType="StudentSysModel.PersonalInfo" Width="1.5" PointX="2.75" PointY="0.875" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a `namespace` conflict.To avoid that error, you have to use correct `namespace` on your class file.If that thing happened suddenly then you can try it again after cleaning the solution.Hope that thing too will sort out your issue.

Comment: OK,then you have to use correct `namespace` on your class above.try that too.

Comment: I write namespace  for Model.Context.cs  and Model.cs  then error goes but when close project again restart it shows error

Comment: when I put namespace it automatically remove and create  Model.Context.cs and Model.cs without namespace but I change in  Model.edmx.diagram it works but   thanks for reply @Sampath